# codeigniter call a view / controller on ajax call sucess

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am new to codeigniter , I am trying to call a controller on AJAX call sucess...
I tried to search stackoverflow but i didn't get what i needed..

Form in my view

```
<form onsubmit="categorysearch()" method="GET">



                <label for="username">Category : </label>
                <select id="category" name="category">
                    <option value="android">android</option>
                    <option value="iphone">iphone</option>
                    <option value="windowsphone">windowsphone</option>
                    <option value="blackberry">blackberry</option>

                </select>


                <input type="submit" name="searchkeywordsubmit" title="Search" id="searchkeywordsubmit" />


            </form>
```

When the form is submitted the below java script is executed.

JavaScript in my View

```
 function categorysearch()
        {
            var categorykeyword = document.getElementById("category").value;
            alert("Category keyword is " + categorykeyword);


            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                async: false,
            //dataType: "json",
            url: "http://localhost/2009074/index.php/rest/resource/categorysearch/category/" + categorykeyword + "",
            success: function(data)
            {

               alert("Returned data is " + data);
               // i want to call the constructor here with the returned data


                //$("body").html(data);

                //$('body').append(output_string);


            },
            error: function(data)
            {
                alert("error is " + data);
            }

        });
    }
```

AJAX call works successfully , I can see the returned data in the alert (Returned data is JSON encoded)

Now i want to call another controller with the recieved data ...
Please help me to figure this out

Comment: What is the execution you need in ajax success? Just view the success data in a view container?

Comment: I want to pass the received data in to a controller function...
IF not possible i want to call another view...

Answer (score 0):

you just need to redirect the control the required controller :

```
success: function(data)
            {

              window.location.href="http://localhost/my_project_name/my_controller_name";// you just need to add this event on success call.

            },
```

Comment: Unfortunately , this code does not work 
on success it goes to this url   http://localhost/2009074/index.php/search?category=android&searchkeywordsubmit=Submit

Comment: I have provide you the sample URL, Make sure you have given the proper URL and it properly redirects you to the desired controller.

Answer (score 0):

A really dirty way to do it is save the JSON object as session variable and navigate to a page  or reload the page and in the constructor of the page, check for the session variable and use the variable.

well that's the only way I can think of at the moment.